# write data frame with variable file name in different directory

Tags: r

I am trying to write a data frame to a particular directory from within a loop so that the file uses a variable as its name. The variable is generated within the loop.

I can write the data frame, `df1` in the directory "DIR1/SUBDIR2" with a unique name, "data.tsv"

```
write.table(df1,  file = "DIR1/SUBDIR2/data.tsv", sep = "\t")
```

I can also write out the data frame, `df1` with a dynamic name based on the variable, "flname" using the following:

```
write.table(df1,paste0("data_",flname,".tsv"))
```

This creates the file in the working directory.

However, I am trying to save the files in DIR1/SUBDIR2 which I cannot. I would appreciate any help on this.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You didn't indicate whether or not you tried this, so try:

```
write.table(df1,paste0("DIR1/SUBDIR2/data_",flname,".tsv"))
```

- just a minor tweak, adds the dir to the path